# Does $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}\cos(\frac{1}{z})$ have an essential singularity in $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

So im doing an exercise that says, that all of the functions defined (in this excercise) have isolated singularities at $z=0$. However, one of them is $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}\cos(\frac{1}{z})$ and im not sure if this function actually has an isolated singularity at $z=0$.

If I do the series expansion,

$$\frac{1}{z}\cos\bigg(\frac{1}{z}\bigg)=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{z} \bigg)^3+\frac{1}{4!}\bigg(\frac{1}{z} \bigg)^5- \dots$$

Which looks like if it had infinite terms in the laurent series expansion for $n<0$ which should mean it has an essencial singularity.

Is this enough to show that it actually has an essential singularity?

Comment: Who told you that $\sin(1/z)$ does not have an isolated singularity at the origin? He lied. Or perhaps you're misremembering the details of what was actually said... Btw the Taylor series, Laurent series, etc, is irrelevant to whather a function has an isolated singularity at a point. The function $\sin(z)/z$ has an isolated singularity at $0$. Hell, let $D=\{z:z\ne0\}$, and define $f:D\to\Bbb C$ by $f(z)=0$. Then $f$ has an isolated singularity at the origin!

Comment: I have actually missread the textbook, it was $\frac{1}{\sin(\frac{1}{z})}$

Comment: Now you've totally changed the question...

Comment: Judging from the question title versus the body, Joaquin, are you using the terms *isolated singularity* and *essential singularity* interchangeably? They differ. This particular function has an isolated singularity at $z=0$ that is classified as essential.

Comment: Oh no! I edited the question and forgot to edit the title!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An isolated singularity is simply a point $z_0$ for which there is a punctured neighborhood of $z_0$ that belongs to the domain of the function. The natural domains of $\sin \left( \frac{1}{z} \right), \cos \left( \frac{1}{z} \right)$ and $\frac{1}{z} \cos \left ( \frac{1}{z} \right)$ are $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ (you can toss in $\infty$ if you want) and so $z = 0$ is an isolated singularity of all those functions.

Answer (score 1):

The function has an essential singularity at $z=0$. The hallmark is the infinitely many negative degree terms in the Laurent series.

Also note that as $z\rightarrow0$, we find that $\frac1z\rightarrow\infty$. The end result is that $\cos(\frac1z)$ oscillates wildly, running through every possible output. This is not indicative of a pole, where the value spikes up to $\infty$, nor is it akin to a removable singularity, where the limit exists.